# React DONUT not working properly when using twice on the same page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, donut-chart

I'm using donut twice on the same page but somehow it's appearing in one div only whereas I defined it in two different Divs

Library : React-donut

```
<div className={this.state.selected == 2 ? "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 selected linkpointer" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 linkpointer"} onClick={this.programsClickEvent}>
    <div className="card p_15 program">
        <div className="mahroon-block">
            <strong>Programs</strong>
        </div>
        <div id = "program-donut">
            <Donut
                chartData={[
                    { name: `${this.state.programCompleted} Completed`, data: this.state.programCompleted },
                    { name: `${this.state.programStarted} Started`, data: this.state.programStarted },
                    { name: `${this.state.programNotStarted} Not Started`, data: this.state.programNotStarted },
                ]}
                chartWidth={100}
                chartHeight={300}
                title=""
                chartThemeConfig={{
                    series: {
                        colors: ['#28B463', '#F39C12 ', '#E74C3C'],
                    },
                }}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div className={this.state.selected == 3 ? "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 selected linkpointer" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 linkpointer"} onClick={this.coursesClickEvent} >
    <div className="card p_15 course">
        <div className="mahroon-block">
            <strong>Courses</strong>
        </div>
        <div id = "course-donut">
            <Donut
                chartData={[
                    { name: `${this.state.courseCompleted} Completed`, data: this.state.courseCompleted },
                    { name: `${this.state.courseStarted} Started`, data: this.state.courseStarted },
                    { name: `${this.state.courseNotStarted} Not Started`, data: this.state.courseNotStarted },
                ]}
                chartWidth={200}
                chartHeight={300}
                title=""
                chartThemeConfig={{
                series: {
                    colors: ['#28B463', '#F39C12 ', '#E74C3C'],
                },
                }}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using two different divs for both the donuts but they are appearing in first div only.

Comment: Using the repo's sandbox you can just copy paste the donut chart and it does indeed work just fine when using it twice on the same page: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-platform-0puu6?file=/src/App.js  so it's likely not an issue with the library. Are you sure the data you're passing to the second donut chart is what you think it is? Creating a sandbox replicating your issue would also be helpful

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks for help! but i need to show 2 donuts in 2 different DIVs but both the donuts are populating in one DIV only even after defining at two different places.

Comment: Could you please add the complete file including the state?

Comment: @SarunUK not able to add complete file as it is too big to upload. Can you mention your email id sothat i can mail you?

Comment: Issue might be you are getting undefined value for chart data from the state

Comment: I have created a sample code using your example - https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sound-vrxbl?file=/src/App.js